# How can I create a Link to an URL containing a fragment identifier?

Tags: uri, 9

Is it possible to create a Link to a node with a hash in url (for opening a special Tab).

I use:

```
Link::createFromRoute('Title', 'entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 77]);
```

And I want to link to: "/node/77#example"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [public static function Link::createFromRoute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Link.php/function/Link%3A%3AcreateFromRoute/9.0.x)

> array $options: The options parameter takes exactly the same structure. See [\Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/9.0.x) for details.

You can pass a 4th argument as an array with a `fragment` key value:

```
Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Title'), 'entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 77], ['fragment' => 'example']);
```